# Can someone help me find the time complexity of the following program?

Tags: big-o

I think the big-O time complexity with be 4^(rows + columns) where rows and columns belong to the grid.

```
class Solution
{  
    public void someMethod(int[][] grid, boolean[][] used)
    {
        compute(grid, 0, 0, 0, used);
    }

    private void compute(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int count, boolean[][] used)
    {
        if(i<0 || j<0 || i>= grid.length || j>=grid[0].length || grid[i][j]==0 || used[i][j])
            return;

        if(grid[i][j] == 1000) // looking to find 1000 from starting position
        {
             return;
        }

        used[i][j] = true;
        compute(grid, i+1, j, count+1, used); // Go down
        compute(grid, i-1, j, count+1, used); // Go up
        compute(grid, i, j+1, count+1, used); // Go right
        compute(grid, i, j-1, count+1, used); // Go left
        used[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what the time complexity would be? Also, it'll be someone can provide good helpful resources/ examples for complex time complexity analysis like 2^n, n^n, n! etc

Comment: The worst-time complexity of the algorithm is proportional to the number of maximal by length simple paths in the grid. I don't think there is an easy answer to this question but I know that counting of such combinatorial objects is extensively explored in "Analytic Combinatorics" by  Robert Sedgewick and Phillipe Flajolet.

Comment: p.s. I believe you know that the problem itself can be easily solved in O(rows * columns) worst time.

Comment: Sure yeah. But I want to find the complexity of this algorithm and I guess it'll hellp me understand finding complexity of complex algo. Weird noone on SO can answer this

Comment: As I mentioned, it doesn't seem to have an easy answer. Also, the question is rather from Theoretical Computer Science than coding. If only right and down moves were allowed, there would be an easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `n = columns` and `m = rows`. For simplicity assume `n == m`.

Short: Your algorithm is `O[ (2.6382)^(n^2) ]` and `Ω[ (1.3196)^(n^2) ]`.

The first being an asymptotic upper bound and the second being an asymptotic lower bound. In any case a function growing as quickly as `c^(n^2)` for some `c>1` is called doubly-exponential. It is growing quicker than any exponential or a factorial.

See derivation below (though some arguments shortened). Better bounds on the particular problem are likely known, I did not research it. This is just giving an idea on how to solve such problems.

---

You want to count the number of maximal self-avoiding paths starting from (0,0) on a 2D grid (n, m). There are some additional costs, like the actual call depth, but they are polynomial corrections, while the full complexity is certainly super-exponential.

I will try to construct in the following better and better upper and lower bounds on the complexity.

Note that self-avoiding paths on the grid can have at most length `n^2` (because after that many steps all of `used` is true). We can therefore also ignore the fact that the paths shall be maximal, because if we count each of the non-maximal sub-paths of the maximal ones as well, it will be at most a polynomial factor `n^2` difference.

At each step of a path we can go 4 directions (4 `compute` calls), therefore the number of relevant paths can be at most `4^(n^2)`.
However we can notice, that at least one of the `4` steps goes back to where we already were (or the start) and therefore is not self-avoiding. Thus an upper bound is also `3^(n^2)`.

Being a bit more creative, we can realize that the number of self-avoiding paths of fixed length `s` starting at a fixed point on an grid infinite in all directions is known to grow up to polynomial factors exponential in `s` with a growth constant `µ`, known as the *connective constant*. For the 2D square lattice is is not exactly known, but it is roughly `µ = 2.6381...`.
Now that is for an infinite grid, so certainly the number of such paths on a finite grid is smaller and the number of paths is also certainly monotonic in `s` and so another upper bound for your problem is `µ^(n^2 + O(log n))`.

Now for the lower bound. Consider the case `n==2`. On this grid every cell can be reached from every other with at least 2 different self-avoiding paths.
Now consider again larger `n` and divide the whole grid into 2x2 sub-grids.
There certainly is at least one self-avoiding path of length `(n/2)^2` on the outer n/2 x n/2 grid that the sub-grids from. But also, as just said on each of the `n^2/4` sub-grids there are at least two equivalent paths to choose from. Therefore the number of relevant paths in total is at least `f_0(n) = 2^(n^2 / 4)`, which is about `(1.189...)^(n^2)`.

Now this we can also improve. Consider `n=4` and divide the grid into `2x2` sub-grids. Then in each sub-grid there are 2 possible paths, as well as at least 2 possible paths in the coarse grid, making `2^5 = 32` paths at least. If now `n` large again, and we divide into sub-grids of length `4`, then with the same argument as before there are at least `f_1(n) = 32^(n^2 / 16) = (1.255...)^(n^2)` such paths.

Repeating this coarse-graining into 2x2 grids we find for each `r` a bound `2^((sum 4^x for x=0..r)/4^(r+1)*n^2)`.
 which for `r` to infinity gives the lower bound `2^(n^2 / 3) = (1.2599...)^(n^2)`.

Now one might try to redo this bound by coarse-graining not into 2x2 grids, but rather into 3x3 grids. Then one can find, that there are at least 9 paths between any pair of border cells and so with the same arguments as above, one will find the bound `9^(n^2 / (3^2-1)) = (1.316...)^(n^2)`.

One can repeat this for other coarse-graining, and I found the best bound for `4x4` grids with an assumed minimum `64` self-avoiding paths between any pair of border cells (might actually be higher, didn't enumerate all) giving `64^(n^2 / 15) = (1.3195...)^(n^2)`.